# Retrieving Metadata from Org using VS Code and CLI results:- MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I am seeing a new warning message when retrieving metadata from VS Code. The metadata retrieval is successful but also getting below message.

**Steps to reproduce:-**

I have created a Lightning Web Component and deployed in the past. When i am again retrieving it, below error message is coming.

> (node:11948) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to
>   increase limit

[image]

Is it something to do with my code or it is specific to VS Code or CLI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a known issue in the CLI and Salesforce is working towards the fix.

The fix is scheduled to go out today (USA PST hours)

Check th details here below

https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/216

FYI - This issue is now fixed as per release notes

https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html

To get the fix run `sfdx update`